# Trigger of Drop-down list to only calculate specific cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I made drop-down lists that only have two choices:
 **BUY** and **SELL**.

What I want is if I clicked BUY, my sheet will just calculate Broker's Commission, VAT on Broker's Commission, PSE Trans Fee, SCCP and the sum will appear on the TOTAL FEES.

Now, if I clicked SELL, I need to calculate all those above PLUS the Sales Tax.

[image: Here is the Image of the whole row.]

How will I do it?

Comment: Suppose the Buy/Sell dropdown is in B2.  Then use `=IF(B2="SELL",C2*.07,"")` in J2.  (This assumes your sales tax is 7%.)

Comment: @Bandersnatch this doesn't work for some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

*Since some of the basic information are not available to calculate Broker's Commission, VAT, PSE Trans Fee, SCCP, in this situation let me assume the values.*

What you have to do is, need to exercise the IF logical test for Buy & Sell to calculate those values. Here, I would like to show you one sample formula. In **Cell F2** write this to get the Broker's Commission.

```
=IF(B2="Sell",E2*5/100,IF(B2="Buy",E2*3/100))
```

Likewise in Cells G2 to J2 you need to apply similar Formula to calculate rest values.

In K2 calculate Total and in L2 the Net Amount.

**NB:** Don't miss to apply YOUR VALUES in all the Formula.

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Thank you for answering. How will enter the formula? Because one cell is related to another cell before it computes?




Gross Amount=Price*Total Shares
Broker's Commision Formula= (Gross Amount) G2*0.25% 
VAT on Broker's Commision= (Broker's Commission)H2*12%
PSE Trans Fee=(Gross Amount)G2*0.005% 
SCCP= (Gross Amount) G2*0.01%
Sales Tax(Selling)= (total shares) F2 * Price * 0.006

Comment: Remember initially you have only 3, first is Drop down value, Sell or Buy, others are Price & Total Share,,write? Your calculation starts from here only,, write ! Start with Commission then VAT and others and you finally get the Net Amount. Hope this help you.

Comment: Let me remind you, any where you have NOT MENTIONED what would be CALCULATING Parameters if in Drop Down column the value will BUY !!

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, here is a summary of the data and formulas:

1. Buy/Sell is selected from the dropdown in D2
2. Price and Total Shares are entered in E2 and F2, respectively.
3. The Gross Amount is calculated in G2 as:  `= E2*F2`
4. The Broker’s Commission (2.5%) is calculated in H2 as: `=
   G2*0.025`
5. The VAT on Broker's Commision (12%) is calculated in I2 as:  `=
   H2*0.12`
6. The PSE Trans Fee (.005%) is calculated in J2 as: `= G2*0.00005`
7. The SCCP (.01%) is calculated in K2 as: `= G2*0.0001`

Finally, to calculate 6% Sales Tax (for Sales transactions only) put this formula in L2:

`=IF(D2="SELL",G2*.06,"")`

Note: It's not clear what you mean in your comment about entering the formula: "Because one cell is related to another cell before it computes?". The formula above uses the value in G2, calculates 6% of it, and returns that result in L2, but only if "SELL" was selected in D2.  Otherwise, the formula returns a blank.

Good luck, and I hope this helps.  Reply back here if you don't get the expected result.